# Asp MVC core 2.0 automapper ('Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.')

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, asp.net-core-2.0

I created the new asp mvc core 2.0 angular template and added models and dtos which I want to map in the controller with Automapper. I included automapper 6.1.1 . When I navigate to http://localhost:61031/api/classes it gives me the exception Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. I read through many posts but are unable to find what is going on.

My code is as follows:

Overview of project
[image]

MODELS

Models.Classes.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Classes
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string ClassName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1, 50)]
        public int MaxStudents { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Students> Students { get; set; } = new List<Students>();
    }
}
```

Models.Students.cs

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Students
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        public Gender Gender { get; set; }



        public Classes Classes { get; set; }

        public int ClassId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Models.EdulyContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class EdulyContext : DbContext
    {
        public EdulyContext(DbContextOptions<EdulyContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.Migrate();
        }

        public DbSet<Classes> Classes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Students> Students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DTOS

Dto.ClassesDtos.ClassesDto.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Dto.ClassesDtos
{
    public class ClassesDto
    {
        public string ClassName { get; set; }

        public int MaxStudents { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Students> Students { get; set; } = new List<Students>();
    }
}
```

Dto.StudentsDtos.StudentDto.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Dto.StudentsDtos
{
    public class StudentsDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        public Gender Gender { get; set; }



        public Models.Classes Classes { get; set; }

        public int ClassId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CONTROLLERS

Controllers.ClassesController.cs

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication1.Dto.ClassesDtos;
using WebApplication1.Repositories.Interfaces;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/classes")]
    public class ClassesController : Controller
    {
        private IClassesRepository _classesRepository;

        public ClassesController(IClassesRepository classesRepository)
        {
            _classesRepository = classesRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet()]
        public IActionResult GetClasses()
        {
            var classesEntities = _classesRepository.GetClasses();
            var results = Mapper.Map<ClassesDto>(classesEntities);

            return Ok(results);

        }

    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = BuildWebHost(args);
            host.Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
        {
            return new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
                {
                    IHostingEnvironment env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;
                })
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using WebApplication1.Dto;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication1.Repositories.Interfaces;
using WebApplication1.Repositories;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            var connectionString = @"server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EdulyDbCore2;Trusted_Connection=True";
            services.AddDbContext<EdulyContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            services.AddScoped<IClassesRepository, ClassesRepository>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
                {
                    HotModuleReplacement = true
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }


            app.UseStaticFiles();


            AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Models.Classes, Dto.ClassesDtos.ClassesDto>();
                cfg.CreateMap<Dto.ClassesDtos.ClassesDto, Models.Classes>();

                cfg.CreateMap<Models.Students, Dto.StudentsDtos.StudentsDto>();
                cfg.CreateMap<Dto.StudentsDtos.StudentsDto, Models.Students>();
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In the startup I mapped both directions from classes to classesDto just to be certain. If anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong, help would be much aprreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After taking a small break I suddenly realized my mistake. 
In classes controller the get return type should be an IEnumerable

so:
   var results = Mapper.Map(classesEntities);

should become:
   var results = Mapper.Map>(classesEntities);